# Codeigniter 3 Shopping Cart Custom Function AJAX error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3, shopping-cart

Good day all, I've scratched my head for the past week trying to figure out this problem. Basically I'm using the Codeigniter 3 shopping cart library in my application. As it has the standard add to cart and remove products from cart, I tried to go one step ahead and tried to implement a quantity increment button with AJAX to make it even better.

So in my cart view, I have a minus button (to decrease the quantity by 1), followed by an input which displays the value quantity, and finally a plus button to increase the quantity by 1.

My problem is one button works flawlessly while the other just doesn't work. If I change my logic for that minus button to add 1 to the quantity instead of deducting 1 it still works as intended.

When I click the button (add_one_product), it fails to increment my quantity by 1, instead it refreshes my page and gives me these errors in console:

1. [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
2. [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952
3. [Violation] 'load' handler took 2308ms

I've read up on synchronous XHR, event listener errors with touchstart etc but I still can't figure out how to fix it.

Here I am sharing my code hoping someone with a better eye and more experience than me could help point out what is it that I am missing.

This is my controller:

```
    function show_cart() {
        $output = '';
        $no = 0;
        foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items) {
            $no++;
            $output .='
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center" scope="row">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 offset-lg-2 offset-md-2 p-0" style="background-image: url('.base_url($items['thumbnail']).'); background-size: cover;">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 p-3" style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px;font-size: 17px;font-family: ProximaNova;letter-spacing: 1px; text-transform: uppercase;">
                                    '.$items['name'].'<br><br>
                                    <button type="button" id="'.$items['rowid'].'" class="remove_cart btn  btn-sm px-0" style="font-weight: 700; color: #892826;text-decoration: underline;font-size: 12px;font-family: ProximaNova;letter-spacing: 1px; background-color: white;">Remove</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <td class="font-weight-bold" style="padding-top: 40px;font-size: 17px;font-family: ProximaNova;letter-spacing: 1px;">RM&nbsp'.number_format($items['price'],2).'</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="input-group w-30" style="padding-top: 25px;">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="button" id="'.$items['rowid'].'" class="remove_one_product btn btn-default btn-number" style="border: 1px solid #892826; color: white; background: #892826;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" style="border: 1px solid #892826" name="qty" class="form-control input-number text-center" value="'.$items['qty'].'" min="0" max="100">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="button" id="'.$items['rowid'].'" class="add_one_product btn btn-default btn-number" style="border: 1px solid #892826; color: white; background: #892826;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="font-weight-bold" style="padding-top:40px;font-size: 17px;font-family: ProximaNova;letter-spacing: 1px;">RM&nbsp'.number_format($items['subtotal'],2).'</td>
                    </tr>
            ';
        }
            $output .= '
            <tr>
                <th style="width:10%;"></th>
                <td style="width:10%;"></td>
                <td style="width:10%;"></td>
                <td style="width:70%;"><h3 style="margin-right: 60px; font-size: 24px; font-weight:bold;margin-top:5px;font-family: ProximaNova;letter-spacing: 1px;">'.'TOTAL: RM '.number_format($this->cart->total(),2).'</h3></td>
            </tr>
            ';
        return $output;
    }

    function add_one_product() {

        $rowid = $this->input->post('row_id');
        $cart=$this->cart->contents();

        foreach ($cart as $items) {
            if($rowid == $items['rowid']){
                $qty = $items['qty'];
            }
        }

        $data = array(
            'rowid' => $rowid,
            'qty' => $qty + 1,
        );
        $this->cart->update($data);
        echo $this->show_cart();
    }

    function remove_one_product() {

        $rowid = $this->input->post('row_id');
        $cart=$this->cart->contents();

        foreach ($cart as $items) {
            if($rowid == $items['rowid']){
                $qty = $items['qty'];
            }
        }

        $data = array(
            'rowid' => $rowid,
            'qty' => $qty - 1,
        );
        $this->cart->update($data);
        echo $this->show_cart();
    }
```

At this point the buttons and functions with the classes and names of add_one_product & remove_one_product is identical, save the naming convention and the + 1 versus -1 operation it does to the quantity of the products in the cart.

In the show_cart function as well the buttons are called and to help with visibility I will recrop them out here again:

```
<div class="input-group w-30" style="padding-top: 25px;">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" id="'.$items['rowid'].'" class="remove_one_product btn btn-default btn-number" style="border: 1px solid #892826; color: white; background: #892826;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
    </button>
  </span>
  <input type="text" style="border: 1px solid #892826" name="qty" class="form-control input-number text-center" value="'.$items['qty'].'" min="0" max="100">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" id="'.$items['rowid'].'" class="add_one_product btn btn-default btn-number" style="border: 1px solid #892826; color: white; background: #892826;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

And finally in my footer, the jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.remove_one_product',function(){
      var row_id=$(this).attr("id");
      $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo base_url('products/remove_one_product');?>",
        method : "POST",
        data : {row_id : row_id},
        success :function(data){
          $('#product_detail_cart').html(data);
          $('#cart-counter').load(location.href + " #cart-counter");
          $('#nav-tab').load(location.href + " #nav-tab");
          $('#nav-home-tab').load(location.href + " #nav-home-tab");
          $('#nav-profile-tab').load(location.href + " #nav-profile-tab");
        }
      });
    });
  });

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.add_one_product',function(){
      var row_id=$(this).attr("id");
      $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo base_url('products/add_one_product');?>",
        method : "POST",
        data : {row_id : row_id},
        success :function(data){
          $('#product_detail_cart').html(data);
          $('#cart-counter').load(location.href + " #cart-counter");
          $('#nav-tab').load(location.href + " #nav-tab");
          $('#nav-home-tab').load(location.href + " #nav-home-tab");
          $('#nav-profile-tab').load(location.href + " #nav-profile-tab");
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

I realise that this is a long post, my thanks for those who took their time to read through it. Any help and constructive criticism is welcomed.

Comment: You're giving multiple buttons the same id. That's not allowed in HTML. All id's _must_ be unique within a document.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I thought about that one too and there's 3 buttons with the same ID. However if I remove the plus button and just leave two buttons with the same ID, it still works, the functionality of Removing all product and reducing the quantity by 1. I know it's not good practice but I can't think of a way to bring in the row.id of the products another way, maybe with input hidden?

Comment: Add a `data`-attribute on the buttons. Something like: `data-id="1337"` on the elements instead. Then you can fetch it with: `let id = $(this).data('id');`. Always make sure the HTML is valid since it otherwise can cause side effects (that may differ between different browsers, making it a pain to debug).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks, will give it a go and see how it plays out

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I've changed as you've suggested but alas the problem is still the same, appreciate the help and knowledge on data-attributes

Comment: *I'm using the Codeigniter 3 shopping cart library in my application*: from the current docs: 
[the Codeigniter Cart Library is **DEPRECATED and should not be used**. It is currently only kept for backwards compatibility.](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html#shopping-cart-class)

Comment: @Vickel Yeah I noticed that, upon doing more reading I realised that it is deprecated because it was using caching and it was unsafe security wise for codeigniter 2. Correct me if I'm wrong or if you know more. Just wanted the basic cart storing in session functionality and just went to expand on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the silliest mistakes I've made by far and I think I'm sure to make more in the future but to help save anyone else who has a similar problem, my problem was that I wrote the config for remove_one_product but I had forgotten to write the same for add_one_product.

*facepalm*